# Put custom middleware last in the chain in a custom next.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to add a ***custom middleware*** to a **custom next.js server**. But there are no specific path patterns that I can tie my middleware to, since these URL's are generated by our CMS and can be pretty much *anything and everything*. So I would like to add my middleware **last in the chain** so to speak. As the final catch-all. But I can't find any documentation on how to achieve this.

I have tried to simply put my middleware last, but that resulted in it never being called.

Working but ugly, and not future proof:

```
//Our custom middleware first
server.get('*', [customMiddleware, standardMiddleware])
...
const customMiddleware = async function (req, res, next) {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
  console.log("Custom middleware. pathname: " + pathname)
  if (pathname.startsWith("/babel/") || pathname.startsWith("/_next/") || pathname.startsWith("/static/") ...etc) {
    return next()
  }
  ///Custom logic here...
}

const standardMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
  console.log("Standard middleware. pathname: " + pathname)
  return handle(req, res)
}
```

Not working:

```
//Our custom middleware last
server.get('*', [standardMiddleware, customMiddleware])
...
const standardMiddleware = function (req, res, next) {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
  console.log("Standard middleware. pathname: " + pathname)
  return handle(req, res)
}

const customMiddleware = async function (req, res, next) {
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
  console.log("Custom middleware. pathname: " + pathname)
  ///Custom logic here...
}
```

When I run above code marked *"Not working"* I expected next.js to handle all requests that it can handle, and then fallback to **customMiddleware** for all other requests. What actually happens is that it never ever fallbacks to **customMiddleware**, it simply returns **404** for unknown paths.

### Update 2019-02-13

Since this doesn't seem to be possible with the current NextJS code, I added this as a [feature request](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6290).

Comment: `return handle(req, res)`: you most certainly need to pass `next` to `handle`, and call it instead of sending a 404 in case the request can't be handled by `handle`. Idem est: make `handle` a proper _middle_ware, not an end-of-chain handler.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How do I "pass next to handle"? How do I "make handle a proper _middle_ware"? Can you give some example code?

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment above:

```
const standardMiddleware = function (req, res, next) { // next is a callback argument here
  const parsedUrl = parse(req.url, true)
  const { pathname, query } = parsedUrl
  console.log("Standard middleware. pathname: " + pathname)
  return handle(req, res, next); // pass it along
}
...
function handle(req, res, next) {
  ...
  if (noRouteEventuallyMatched) {
    // res.status(404).sendFile('/path/to/my404.html');
    next(); // instead of setting res, call next so that the next element in the chain is tried
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, **handle** is the request handler of Next. It is not part of my code. And as far as I can see (from trial and error), I can't make it call **next()** when it can't handle the request.

Comment: Oh OK, I didn't get that. Well then it's not great, but there might be a workaround: calls to `getRequestHandler`'s returned function (i.e. your `handle`) return a promise: you can `then` it and check `res.statusCode` to handle `next()` yourself depending on the case. However, I see that 500 and 501 codes will have called `res.end()` already... just to tell how dirty this trick is, I don't think it's the way they expect you to use Next.js. A cleaner way would be to check beforehand whether your `handle` will end with a 404 (check `/pages/<requestedFile>` I suppose).

Comment: Yes, seems a bit dirty to rely on catching an exception to handle the normal workflow. But I submitted a feature request to the nextjs team. Hopefully they see it as a good thing to add to an already excellent product. :)